# Is it possible to run unit tests on code that uses subprocess?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

My Django app has some management commands that start other management commands using `subprocess.Popen(['manage.py', '<command>', ...)`. They are kept like this mainly to run processes in parallel and prevent one command from interfering with another.

However, when writing **unit tests** these new processes don't use the test environment and database and therefore fail.

For now, I've added a setting that runs `call_command()` instead of `Popen()` (see below):

```py
        if settings.TESTING:
            self.returncode = call_command(self.command, *params)
        else:
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'manage.py', self.command] + params)

            # ... later on:
            self.process.wait()
            self.returncode = self.process.returncode
```

However the subprocess calls and the logic involved in waiting remains untested. Is it possible to test subprocess calls within the unit tests?

Note: the test database is not an in-memory SQLite - I know that wouldn't work. It's an actual database that is created and destroyed every run.

Comment: It sounds like what database the code hits should be controlled by env variables.  When you start testing and spin up the test database, you can also set the env variables.

Comment: If you considered it as a unittest, mock your command calls to return data or what ever you need to make sure that command caller works fine - 1 Unit. And then write another test to test command only - another unit.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo That actually makes a lot of sense. If you turn this into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you considered it as a unit-test, then you could mock your command calls to return mock data to make sure that command caller works just fine.

And for the coverage for the command code, you could also write another unit-test only for that command by using `call_command` method which provided by Django.

Like so:

```py
class TestYourCommandCaller(TestCase):
    ...

    @mock.patch('subprocess.Popen')
    def test_your_business_which_call_the_command(self, mock_process):
        # Mock your process

        call_your_function_which_create_processes()

        # Assert your process have been called
```

and another test for your command to also coverage command code:

```py
class TestYourCommand(TestCase):
    def test_command_call(self):
        call_command('command_name', *params)

        # Assert the result
```